# Lock Screen and Logged Out screen

Tags: high-sierra, customization

So, on High Sierra, I know how to change the login screen for when a user logs out by changing the com.apple.desktop.admin.png file in /Library/Caches. And this works fine when you log out, however I was wondering if there was customization to where it would display on lock screen? Because as of currently, when the screen gets locked it goes to a low transparency picture of the background.

Comment: I think that what this question refers to as the "Logged Out" screen also appears when you click "Switch User".

Comment: Maybe the lock screen comes from somewhere in the user's directory rather than the system directory? It would make sense, since the desktop background is on a per-user basis.